# Customize author in Facebook share

Tags: facebook

I have a page of blog posts by different authors, with share kits that correctly share the entire page or an individual post.  The meta tag at the top of my page grabs all the authors and shares correctly.  What I can't figure out is how to change that per blog post--sharing an individual post shows the authors of the page as a whole instead of the correct author of an individual post.

Basically:  Is there a way to list the author for a Facebook share other than using the meta tag, which is per page instead of per post?

EDITED:  The URL for each individual post is of the format www.site.com/mainpost#individual_post where the hash jumps to the individual post

Comment: Have a unique url for each blog post and put the author og tags on that url

Comment: @WizKid Added a bit about my url structure--if your solution is still viable, can you elaborate?

Comment: No you need a fetchable unique url.

Comment: That's what I thought; thanks anyway!